# Subtracting TIMESTAMP from current date

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm trying to create an update system in which the user is told when the update was posted in the following format: Posted by user1 1 hour, 10 minutes ago.

When the update is created the date is stored in the db as TIMESTAMP.

I can't seem to successfully subtract this from the current date (`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`) in order to do this.

Here's the output. As you can see, both the date the update was made (stored date) and current date are of the same format.

```
Update posted on: 2012-01-24 20:03:27
Current date is:  2012-02-04 19:25:09
```

Comment: [The TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Comment: Is the problem updating the column or is the problem getting the "1 hour, 10 minutes ago."? The latter has been answered a dozen times before and you are encouraged to use the search function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use next code:

```
$delta_time = time() - strtotime($timestamp);
$hours = floor($delta_time / 3600);
$delta_time %= 3600;
$minutes = floor($delta_time / 60);

echo "{$hours} hours ago and {$minutes} and minutes";
```